# Top padding in NSTableView Cell

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I want to add some space from top in NSTextFieldCell, I have searched , i found there is way with subclassing. But by this way my touch event for table doesn't work. if i use TextFieldCell's touch events then also i can't find real data according to cell for deletion and other actions.

So this will be better if there is possible way for doing this. Thanks a lot.